# How to dry android gradle classpath versioning?

Tags: android, gradle

I have more than 100 Android applications, and it's increasing.

One problem that I have is that the gradle plugin is becoming a pain. In each top-level `build.gradle` file we have this line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Now if I want to upgrade gradle plugin to `3.2.1` I need to change it in many files over many source controls. This is not efficient.

Is there a way for me to centralize/DRY this line of configuration and reuse it across other `build.gradle` files?